# How to modify "runAsNonRoot" option for a Container with cdk8s

Tags: typescript, kubernetes, cdk8s

i am atm trying to get familiar with cdk8s and try to deploy a container to a cluster. All this is working fine until i want to run the container as root user (i know it's not best practice but i want to have the option to).

I have the following class:

```
export class WebService extends Chart {
  Service: kplus.Service
  IngressBackend: kplus.IngressBackend
  Container: kplus.Container

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: WebServiceProps) {
    super(scope, id)
    
    const port = props.port || 80
    // const containerPort = props.containerPort || 8080
    const label = { app: Names.toDnsLabel(this) }
    const replicas = props.replicas ?? 1
    const deployment = new kplus.Deployment(scope, Names.toDnsLabel(this), {
      replicas: replicas,
      metadata: { labels: label },
    })

    this.Container = deployment.addContainer({
      image: props.image,
      port: port,

    })
```

The Webservice has an interface which declares all the necessary stuff.
I would expect this to work:

```
 this.Container = deployment.addContainer({
      image: props.image,
      port: port,
      securityContext: {
        runAsNonRoot: false, 
      },
    })
```

But it seems the runAsNonRoot option is not part of the ContainerSecurityContextProps interface. The option is part of the underlying SecurityContext Interface so I was thinking about useing an escape hatch: [https://cdk8s.io/docs/latest/basics/escape-hatches/](https://stackoverflow.com) but honestly i got no clue how to even start with that (i am relativly new to typescript so i don't really understand the documentation for it)

If somebody could point out to me how to use the escape-hatches that would be awesome.